# Word starting with pre- meaning "enabled" or "set the foundations for"

Tags: single-word-requests

> The collapse of clear chains of responsibility can be seen as one of the most important factors which pre_______ the company's bankruptcy.

It's not preceded, because that simply means "came before".

But I am looking specifically for a word that means

- enabled
- laid the foundations for
- allowed X to happen
- set up

With a more negative (or at least neutral) connotation.

I guess this word can appropriately be applied to the constituents of any "perfect storm".

Comment: The factors are *precursors* of the bankruptcy, but we do not say that the factors *precurse* the bankruptcy.

Comment: How do you know that there _is_ such a word starting with _pre_? Have you looked for synonyms for 'enable'?

Comment: 'Predestine' is in the same general area, but is largely confined to the religious domain (or notions of 'fate').

Comment: Why are you specifically looking for a word that starts with "pre"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth idk how I know there is such a word, I've never actually thought about that before. That's quite a complex question. "It's on the tip of my tongue" is an idiom to describe it so I guess lots of people have this feeling.

Comment: The question is better put then "Is there a word ... (I feel it's on the tip of my tongue)? ... I think it starts with pre.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why is it better put that way? I know it starts with pre...

Comment: 'idk how I know there is such a word' shows incontestably a level of uncertainty. Though you may 'feel sure' such a word exists, unless and until such a word is provided, there is no guarantee as to what level of uncertainty you have. We've had people ask similar questions only to come up later with "Oh, it starts 'pri' instead". It's unfair to give a requirement which may or may not be allowable if you can't demonstrate that it's correct. If you can't prove something, don't go beyond "I'm almost certain that there's a word ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Precipitated** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precipitate

> to make something happen suddenly or sooner than expected:
>
> - An invasion would certainly precipitate a political crisis.
> - Fear of losing her job precipitated (= suddenly forced) her into action.

Answer (score 2):

Words that would fit in your sentence:

Predicted, prepared, presaged, precipitated, predetermined, prefigured

Words that require a (small) change or rearrangement to it:

Precursor, preliminary, prerequisite, predisposed, prelude,

Comment: I don't think most of these fit OP's requirements. A suitable dictionary definition is considered almost mandatory on ELU for SWRs.

Comment: I was looking for **precipitated**. I feel hesitant to accept your answer though bc there's so many things in it....

Comment: @theonlygusti No problem. As has been pointed out it's not a very good answer, but I'm glad it's been useful to you 

Answer (score 0):

The word you  are looking for may be  *preluded* or *predisposed*.

> The collapse of clear chains of responsibility can be seen as one of the most important factors which *preluded*  or *predisposed* the company's bankruptcy.

*Prelude* means something that comes before a more important event or action that introduces or prepares for it.

*Predisposed* means make an impact in a certain way.

See the links

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prelude

Comment: "preluded" (or predated) doesn't include any causality. "predisposed" seems to be an adjective to an entity such as "the company" in the sentence. I've not heard of a predisposed bankruptcy yet.